# Composition in practice

Tags: composition

In university, we are taught that a composition is quite important to keep your code clean and efficient. For example, a playtile class object could **only** exist in a playfield class object. If there is no playfield, there could not be a playtile. However, we were never taught **how** to implement such a thing. When I asked, I got an answer similar to "Add a check in the constructor." or something along those lines but I have no clue on how I would implement that (I don't know what to look for or what the official terms are). One of my attempts was inheritance. The teachers did  not like that, let's keep it at that...

So, how does a composition work in practice? How could I make it so the playfield class is the **only**  class that could instantiate a playtile without inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice a class that references another doesn't impose constraints on the class it references.   Its not desirable for a class to care about what is referencing it.  For example: you would not want to enforce this constraint when you write unit tests.  I would never make it so the playfield class is the only class that could instantiate a playtile.

For a concrete example of how composition is implemented in the wild, check out the Unity3d game engine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TIkManpEu4

Comment: Unity3D uses Entity-Component System architecture, which is an "extreme" version of composition (objects can be composed dynamically), so it isn't representative for composition as such.

Comment: How is an extreme case not representative?

Comment: Sooo, the whole idea of a composition could get thrown out of the window on implementation? It's just a theoretical thing?

Comment: Its just choosing has-a relationships instead of is-a relationships.  If you are looking for a language feature, c# has partial classes,  but you don't need a language feature to do it.   In your playtile example, lets say you were making go.  The inheritance way would be to make a playtile base class and derive blacktile and whitetile from it.  The compostion way would be to make a playtile class with a color member variable that can be either black or white.